# Identifying Mains Connector for Bosch 300/500/800 Series Dishwashers

Tags: identification, appliances, power-connector

Bosch dishwashers do not ship with a simple junction box built into the front quarter, as most dishwashers do.  Instead, they use a 3-pin connector; presumably because this approach allows them to sell you an extra part (their plug with a cord ending in your country's local plug, or else their plug terminating in a simple junction box).

Unfortunately, the latter option, which goes by the model number of SMZPCJB1UC, is somewhat famous both for having anemic wire gauge, and for occasionally burning out its terminal block (in the most literal sense imaginable; check out the pictures attached to reviews of it on Home Depot's website).  Thus, I'd rather not use the official offering.

This means I need to locate a source for their plug, which appears pretty generic—a simple 90°, 3-pin connector.  To do that, though, I need a name, or at least dimensions.  So does anyone recognize this plug?

[image: Bosch 300/500/800-series dishwasher power plug]

Alternatively, if you have a Bosch dishwasher and would be willing to take a set of calipers to its plug, that would allow me to find it on any of the various connector-searching websites.

To be clear, I don't mind if this plug (plus any required crimping tools) are more expensive than just buying their kit and modifying it; after all, this is about safety, not saving money.

[A note, for the sake of others searching for this later: in some markets, Bosch also markets dishwashers under the names Thermador and Gaggenau.]

Answer (score 1):

I found tons of cables with moulded variants of the connector. Unfortunately no standalone. You can find various cables with the connector by googling "GD3A plug" or the Partnumber of the cable "12005926". Since you just want to attach your local power plug to the other end of the cable anyways, that should do.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have one to measure, but I found just the cable for sale below.

This one looks easier to cut and splice into your own junction box.
https://partsdr.com/part/12010974-power-cord/

This one is more suited to plugging into a wall outlet.
https://partsdr.com/part/12027214-power-cord

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, the issue that people are facing is the junction block inside the junction box.
The cable and the box itself seems fine.

Then you could just purchase the junction box but remove the junction block from inside the box and replace it with whatever you prefer (I'd personally recommend Wago 221) and be done with it.